# Calling string manipulation functions in Makefile returns empty variable

Tags: makefile

I have this tiny Makefile:

```
SERVICE := $(call lc,$(SERVICE))
 $(info lowercase "$(SERVICE)")
```

It should print $SERVICE environment variable in lowercase. Unfortunatelly it does not:

```
bash$ SERVICE=Test make
lowercase ""
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Any ideas how to set the variable correctly? I've tried it exactly from best response at [In GNU Make, how do I convert a variable to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664601/in-gnu-make-how-do-i-convert-a-variable-to-lower-case) but it still did not work.

Comment: if _SERVICE_ is understand as shell variable that you want to access in makefile then double dollar shall be used: `$$SERVICE`. Otherwise you access make variable that can be resolved as empty string when not defined.

Comment: Properly include `gmsl` before using it: `include gmsl`.

Comment: @Blueman I've seen it, actually I've found how to lowercase strings exactly at this page. But it did not solve my problem.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Yes, that's it. I thought GNU Make Standard Library is installed by default if you install make.

Comment: @MichalŠpondr other problem is that you override _SERVICE_ variable so you should  use other name for makefile variable or explicitly do it with `override` keyword

Comment: @Blueman I had this problem when I was using `=` instead of `:=`.