# How to uppercase '$*' value from makefile target?

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching, uppercase, variable-names

I have a bunch of targets, each for a different shell as follow:

```
BASH_VERSION := 4.4
FISH_VERSION := 3.0.0
…
ZSH_VERSION := 5.4.2-r1

.PHONY: dev-pure-on-bash
dev-pure-on-bash:
    $(MAKE) dev-pure-on TARGET=bash VERSION="${BASH_VERSION}" ARGS="VERSION=${BASH_VERSION}"

.PHONY: dev-pure-on-elvish
dev-pure-on-elvish:
    $(MAKE) dev-pure-on TARGET=elvish VERSION="${ELVISH_VERSION}" ARGS="VERSION=${ELVISH_VERSION}"

.PHONY: dev-pure-on-fish
dev-pure-on-fish:
    $(MAKE) dev-pure-on TARGET=fish VERSION="${FISH_VERSION}" ARGS="VERSION=${FISH_VERSION}"

…

.PHONY: dev-pure-on-xonsh
dev-pure-on-xonsh:
    $(MAKE) dev-pure-on TARGET=xonsh VERSION="${XONSH_VERSION}" ARGS="VERSION=${XONSH_VERSION}"

.PHONY: dev-pure-on-zsh
dev-pure-on-zsh:
    $(MAKE) dev-pure-on TARGET=zsh VERSION="${ZSH_VERSION}" ARGS="VERSION=${ZSH_VERSION}"

.PHONY: dev-pure-on
dev-pure-on:
    docker run \
        --name run-pure-on-${TARGET} \
        --rm \
        --interactive \
        --tty \
        --volume=$$PWD:/home/pure/.pure/ \
        pure-on-${TARGET}-${VERSION}
```

#### Attempt

I tried to use a [pattern rule](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Make_(software)#/Pattern_rules) without success:

```
dev-pure-on-%:
    $(MAKE) dev-pure-on TARGET=$* VERSION="${$*_VERSION}" ARGS="VERSION=${$*_VERSION}"
```

However I need the `$*` in `${$*_VERSION}` to be uppercase

#### Question

How do I uppercase the value of `$*` inside and use it in another variable?

Comment: Use shell/tr, it's much easier. To uppercase purely in make look for gmsl (GNU Make Standard Library).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In GNU Make, how do I convert a variable to lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664601/in-gnu-make-how-do-i-convert-a-variable-to-lower-case)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Matt suggested, why don't you use something like:

```
UC = $(shell echo '$*' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
```

then use `$(UC)` in place of `$*`.  Or if you want to do it more generically:

```
UC = $(shell echo '$1' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
```

then use `$(call UC,$*)` (or anything else instead of `$*`).

Using recursion trying to use special shell facilities seems like a lot of overhead just to uppercase a string.

Comment: thanks, it's indeed better, I was wrongly placing it in the target body instead of before the target. I will update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Please, upvote [@MadScientist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55404783/802365) which lead me to my full implementation.

---

In my first attempt to use `tr` I was wrongly placing the code in the target body instead of before the target (as `make` code).

#### Solution

```
BASH_VERSION := 4.4
ZSH_VERSION := 5.4.2-r1

shell = $*
shell_name = $(shell echo '$*' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
shell_version = ${${shell_name}_VERSION}

.PHONY: dev-pure-on-%
dev-pure-on-%:
    @echo ${shell} ${shell_version}
    docker run \
        --name run-pure-on-${shell} \
        --rm \
        --interactive \
        --tty \
        --volume=$$PWD:/home/pure/.pure/ \
        pure-on-${shell}-${shell_version}
```

- `shell` is not necessary but provide more meaning than `$*`
- `shell_name` is the uppercase shell name
- `shell_version` expand `shell_name` then expand the resulting variable (e.g. `ZSH_VERSION`, `BASH_VERSION`, etc.)

#### Usage

```
make dev-pure-on-bash
make dev-pure-on-zsh
```